# SharePoint Designer 2013 workflow Error HTTP 500 on send email

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, workflow-manager

I'm trying to send email from SP Designer 2013 workflow, and getting below error.
I've added an App Step and tried send mail from there.
I've register workflow app using appinv.aspx with full-control. 
But No success.
This is a new SharePoint 2013 new single server instance. Can anyone have any answer for this.
Thank you

ananda

Error Details-

> RequestorId: 165a8859-ad9a-c251-7a8b-0ed810cd1946. Details:
>   System.ApplicationException: HTTP 500
>   {"Transfer-Encoding":["chunked"],"X-SharePointHealthScore":["0"],"SPClientServiceRequestDuration":["425"],"SPRequestGuid":["fe53b99b-0f38-4944-8065-0c2dc7c280e4"],"request-id":["fe53b99b-0f38-4944-8065-0c2dc7c280e4"],"X-FRAME-OPTIONS":["SAMEORIGIN"],"MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices":["15.0.0.4569"],"X-Content-Type-Options":["nosniff"],"X-MS-InvokeApp":["1;
>   RequireReadOnly"],"Cache-Control":["max-age=0, private"],"Date":["Thu,
>   07 Sep 2017 12:27:13
>   GMT"],"Server":["Microsoft-IIS/8.5"],"X-AspNet-Version":["4.0.30319"],"X-Powered-By":["ASP.NET"]}
>   at
>   Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.Runtime.Subroutine.SubroutineChild.Execute(CodeActivityContext
>   context) at
>   System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance
>   instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
>   at
>   System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor
>   executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)